# visual studio failed to detect code return path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

I experienced on when refactoring some code, maybe I'm blind but I failed to see why the following code won't work.

```
public bool Foo()
{
    try
    {
        return SomeFunctionMightThrow();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

So far so good, if I refactor code to

```
public bool Foo()
{
  try
  {
    return SomeFunctionMightThrow();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogAndThrow(ex);
  }
}

private void LogAndThrow(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.log(ex);
  throw ex;
}
```

Code does not compile now.

Comment: I presume that you're just using this as an example, so that you _do_ actually know that you should never use `throw ex;` that way?

Comment: Yep, this example is just to show VS failed to detect code return path.

Comment: John Saunders, you got me curious now. I'm not a very experienced programmer, so could you elaborate on your comment? Why should one not use `throw ex;` that way, and how should it be used?

Comment: @xbonez if you are growing a caught exception you should use throw; (that is, without the variable) rather than throw ex;

Comment: @John Saunders +1, I did not even think about that, I was blindly "simplified" code from thow new SomeOtherExceptions("something is wrong!",ex);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially change it to...

```
public bool Foo()
{
  try
  {
    return SomeFunctionMightThrow();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // note: this will reset the exception stack trace
    throw LogAndReturnException(ex);
  }
}

private Exception LogAndReturnException(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.log(ex);
  return ex;
}
```

This essentially does exactly what you want but gives VS the code return path.

Or for a more simplistic approach which will retain the stack trace, just change your catch to:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Log(ex);
  throw; // retains stack trace
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't take into account that your `LogAndThrow()` method always will throw an exception - that being the case all code paths in `Foo()` must return a boolean, so you *could* just do this:

```
public bool Foo()
{
  try
  {
    return SomeFunctionMightThrow();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogAndThrow(ex);
    return false; //will never get here
  }
}
```

In general since you throw anyway I would recommend using a `try/catch` block at a single central spot in your app for logging, i.e. at the highest level **unless** you can really handle the exception - it doesn't look like you are here.

Comment: In my point of view dead code is bad, it will confuse the code reader, even it is IDE's fault. Code has been simplified as you can tell just to show the exact problem I am asking.

Comment: @Yuan: still the point remains - you shouldn't trigger exception logging within each method, do it **once** at a higher level, it's just as bad to litter your code with try/catch blocks.

Comment: How did you know I log exception at every level? and why Foo() will not be my top level?

Comment: because `Foo()`returns a bool? Surely its being called from somewhere.

Comment: what if Foo() is in a WCF Service class and called by WCF client?

Comment: Yes, admittedly that would be a valid case

Comment: I do agree logging exceptions should be done only once. I am trying to focus on this specific question. return false does not make it better, why not return true? If I have to write something, I'd might just use throw; But it is a shame VS failed to analyze such code.